# How to query two collection in mongoose on nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hi am new to nodeJs i have to query a table from the result of the query, i have to query another table. i tried the code as follows but it returns only null.

```
 action(function getpositions(req){
 var namearray = [];
 NHLPlayerStatsDaily.find ({"created_at": {$gt: new Date(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)}}, function(err,position){
    if(!err)
    { 
    for (i=0;i< position.length; i++)
    {  
        var obj = JSON.stringify(position[i]);
        var pos = JSON.parse(obj);

        var p = pos["player_stats_daily"]["content"]["team_sport_content"]["league_content"]["season_content"]["team_content"]["team"]["id"]
        NHLTeam.find({"sdi_team_id": p}, "first_name nick_name short_name sport_id", function(err, team){
                 if (!err){
                    var obj = JSON.stringify(team);
                    var pos = JSON.parse(obj);
                    namearray.push(team)
                   }
            })
        }
      return send(namearray);
    }
      })
       })
```

if i just push "p" it shows the result and when am query "NHLTeam" in separate function it also shows the result. when querying a collection with in collection it return null. how to query a collection within a collection in mongoose. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a query problem, it is callback issue. The `send(namearray)` is called before any of the `NHLTeam` queries in the loop are completed (remember the result of these queries is passed to callback asynchronously).

What you can do is this (basically tracking when all callbacks are completed):

```
NHLPlayerStatsDaily.find ({"created_at": {$gt: new Date(y+"-"+m+"-"+d)}}, function(err,position){
  if(!err)
  { 
    var total = position.length;

    for (i=0;i< position.length; i++)
    {  
      var obj = JSON.stringify(position[i]);
      var pos = JSON.parse(obj);

      var p = pos["player_stats_daily"]["content"]["team_sport_content"]["league_content"]["season_content"]["team_content"]["team"]["id"]
      NHLTeam.find({"sdi_team_id": p}, "first_name nick_name short_name sport_id", function(err, team){
        total--;
        if (!err){
          var obj = JSON.stringify(team);
          var pos = JSON.parse(obj);
          namearray.push(team);
        }
        if(total == 0)
            send(namearray);
      })
    }

  }
})
```